# Python - Insert inner lists into a nested list at specific indices

Tags: python, insert, nested-lists

Say I have a nested list such as:

```
a = [[4,5,7],[3,5,7],[5,8,0]]
```

I want to insert the inner list `z=[0,0,0]` into specific locations within the list `a`. The locations are determined by a list call index.

So if the index list is:

```
index = [2,4,5]
```

The result would be `z` inserted into `a` at locations 2,4 and 5. The resultant list would be:

```
a_insert = [[[4,5,7],[3,5,7],[0,0,0],[5,8,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

                                2               4       5  
                                ^               ^       ^
```

Where the list `[0,0,0]` is now inserted at the locations specified by the list `index`.

A naive attempt is,

```
for ind in index:
    c = a.insert(ind,z)
```

which does not work. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: `c` will always be bound to `None`, since `insert` mutates the list in-place and does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your given code seems to work just fine here.

```
In [1]: a = [[4,5,7],[3,5,7],[5,8,0]]
In [2]: z = [0,0,0]
In [3]: index = [2,4,5]
In [4]: for ind in index:
   ...:     a.insert(ind, z)
In [5]: a
Out[5]: [[4, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7], [0, 0, 0], [5, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I noticed that your last line attempts to insert into the list `b`. Could this be a typo, since you referred to the list `a` previously?

**Edit**

Your updated code snippet in the original post is now:

```
for ind in index:
    c = a.insert(ind,z)
```

`c` will always be `None` after such an operation. `z` will, however, be inserted into `a` in the manner that your post describes, and `a`'s contents will be updated in-place.

This is because `insert` directly modifies the given list, and does not return any value (other than `None`).

Perhaps you wanted to keep the original list `a` as it was, and create a new list, `c`, with the values inserted? In that case, a simple solution would be as follows:

```
c = a[:] # Create a shallow copy of a
for ind in index:
    c.insert(ind, z)

# a is now [[4, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7], [5, 8, 0]]
# c is now [[4, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7], [0, 0, 0], [5, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Yes, that was a typo - fixed now :)